# Constructing linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I am struggling to figure out a linq statement that I would think is a very common scenario. Assuming the structure below, I have many users, each users has many diaries, each diary has many widgets.

I would like to say, get me the user where UserName = 'bob' and Password = 'password' and that users diaries where DisabledByAdmin == true and the list widgets where DisabledByAdmin == true only the diaries the previous statement returned.

Assuming the data is 1 user that is linked to 2 diaries (one has DisabledByAdmin == true), and those 2 diaries each have 2 widgets (1 has DisabledByAdmin == true), I would like to get my user object back that would have 1 diary object in my list and 1 widget in EACH diary.

So the return data would be user object, with one diary and one widget in that diary collection. For the life of me, I can't figure that out.

Anyone?

Thanks very much
Ralph

```
public class Widget
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool DisabledByAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool DisabledByUser { get; set; }
}
public class DigtalDiary
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool DisabledByAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool DisabledByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
public class User 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DigtalDiary> Diaries { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
    var users from u in UserList
          where u.UserName = "Bob" and u.Password = "123";

    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, List<DigitalDiary>>();
    foreach(var u in users)
    {
        var digitalDiaries = from dd in u.Diaries
                             where dd.DisabledByAdmin != true; //Or whatever your criteria
        lookup.add(u.Id, digitalDiaries.toList());
    }
```

This will give you a dictionary of UserId's that match your criteria, and a list of Ditital Diaries for that user that aren't disabled and whatnot.
Then you can repeat that for Widgets
(Also this was just coded out in the window here, so there might by typos)

Edit:
Also you could use a

```
         new Dictionary<User, List<DigitalDiary>>();
```

if you'll be wanting the full User Fields as soon as you're done. I'm just used to storing keys

Comment: Oh and this is assuming there might be more than one User that matches your criteria... if you know for sure you'll only be getting one back, it would be a bit simpler as you wouldn't need Lists

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question **AND you are using EntityFramework**

You may need to play with the Select Projection to meet your requirements.
  This example is an AND,   use || for or condition as appropriate

```
var mylist = Context.Set<User>.Where(u=>u.Id==userId && u.Password==password
                              && u.Diaries.DiabledByAdmin == false
                              && u.Diaries.Widgets.DisabledByAdmin == false)
                          .Select(new {u.Id, u.Diaries.Id,u.Diaries.Widgets.Id}); //remove select if user Object desired
```

Comment: The `Diaries` property in `User` is a list, and therefor will not have a `DisabledByAdmin` property.  You need to pull the values from within the list that have that property set to true.  Same goes for the `Widgets` property in each `Diary`.

Comment: I got the impression this wasn't a Linq2Sql question, so there is no data context, just a few Lists of Users, Widgets and Diaries, but yeah, if this is coming straight from a database, it'd be a lot simpler

Comment: sorry this is an EF question. For ease, I am only using one of the bool. This is what I want.

     User oUser = context.Users.Where(e => e.UserName ==  objUser.UserName && e.Password == objUser.Password).Select(d => d.Diaries.Where(dd => dd.DisabledByAdmin == false).Select(w => w.Widgets.Select(ww => ww.DisabledByAdmin = false)));

  Note, this doesn't work but was hoping for a statement like the one above. So again, give me my EF user whos diaries have DisabledByAdmin == false and in THOSE diaries, give me the widgets who have DisabledByAdmin == false AND put it ALL in my oUser object.

Comment: if you just want the full user object back, just drop .select part    Assume you tried replacing the true with false.  You can combine && and || statements

Comment: NOTE: If you can Diaries with no widgets then you need change the where clause by adding || Ill update sample

Comment: How do you write the query to do the where on the collection and then the where on the RETURNED collection. I do not think this can be done in one linq query.

Comment: A where on the returned set is logically a just an and condition.   If you want to work with data in the context ONLY.   Then you can access Context.Set<User>.Local but that seems an usual approach to me.  You can also execute Linq commands on the returned set. The result Type should be an IQuerable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, assuming that you have a `List` collection of `User` of name `myUserList`, you may iterate through this list only getting the values you are looking for. Then, if the values you are looking for were found, you may add the `User` responsible with these values to a new `List` collection of `User`.

**Example**

```
List<User> myUserList = new List<User>(); //Initialize a new List of Users

//Add users to the list
myUserList.Add(new User() { UserName = "bob", Password = "password" });
myUserList.Add(new User() { UserName = "Joe", Password = "password" });
myUserList.Add(new User() { UserName = "Miranda", Password = "password" });
myUserList.Add(new User() { UserName = "Kevin", Password = "password" });
//

List<User> myGatheredList = new List<User>(); //Initialize a new List of Users of name myGatheredList (not required)
foreach (User _user in myUserList.Where(x => x.UserName == "bob" && x.Password == "password")) //Only get values which match a UserName of value 'bob' and a password of value 'password' as _user for every User
{
    Debug.WriteLine(_user.UserName); //Writes 'bob'.
    foreach (DigtalDiary _diary in _user.Diaries) //Get every DigitalDiary in _user.Diaries as _diary for every DigitalDiary
    {
        if (_diary.DisabledByAdmin /*&& _diary.Widgets.Count == x */ /* More conditions can be inserted here */) //Continue if _diary.DisabledByAdmin is true
        {
            foreach (Widget _widget in _diary.Widgets) //Get every Widget in _diary.Widgets as _widget for every Widget
            {
                if (_widget.DisabledByAdmin) //Continue if _widget.DisabledByAdmin is true
                {
                    if (!myGatheredList.Contains(_user)) //Continue if _user does not exist in myGatheredList
                    {
                        myGatheredList.Add(_user); //Add _user to myGatheredList (not required)
                       //Do something with _user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTICE**: This will only get the Users which have got at least ONE `DigitalDiary` disabled by admin and ONE `Widget` disabled by admin.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Wouldn't this return a lot of duplicates, if a user has three Diaries and each of his Diaries has 3 Widgets that are disabled. You'd have the same user 9 times in the myGatheredList

Comment: @MikeyMouse You are certainly right! I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out :)